# Why does uint break my for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is not really a problem as the fix is simple and pretty costless. I'm guessing it's some property of `for` or `uint` that I don't understand and I just would like to know what is going on so...

Using ActionScript 3 I set up a `for` loop to run backwards through the elements of a `Vector`.

```
var limit:uint = myVector.length-1;
for(var a:uint = limit; a >= 0; a--)
{
    trace(a);
}
```

When I run this it outputs `2, 1, 0` as expected but then moves on to `4294967295` and begins counting down from there until the loop times out and throws an `Error #1502`.

The fix is simply to type `a` as `int` rather than `uint` but I don't get why. Surely I am dealing with values of 0 and greater so `uint` is the correct data type right?

I guess that `4294967295` is the max value for `uint` but how does my count get there?

If you do

```
var myUint:uint = 0;
trace(myUint - 1);
```

Then the output is `-1` so why, in my loop should I suddenly jump back up to `4294967295`?

Sorry for the slightly rambling question and cheers for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. As you said, your loop gives you 2, 1, 0, 4294967295. This is because uint can't be negative. Your loop will always run while `a >= 0` and since it is never -1 to break the loop condition, it continues to loop forever.

```
var myUint:uint = 0;
trace(myUint - 1);
```

I didn't test this but what is probably happening is that myUint is being converted to an int and then having 1 subtracted. The following code should be able to confirm this.

```
var myUint:uint = 0;
trace((myUint - 1) is uint);
trace((myUint - 1) is int);
```

To fix your loop you could use int or you could use a `for each(var x:Type in myVector)` loop if you don't need the index (`a`).

Comment: You're right. `myUint-1` is indeed typed as `int`. This actually makes perfect sense now you mention it. The output is the result of a calculation using data of a certain type but that type has no bearing on the type of the output.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to confirm my thoughts. I've updated my answer to provide a possible solution for your loop.

Answer (score 3):

an iteration and a a-- will occur when a is 0, thus as your int is not signed, the max value for this type will be set -> this is the way minus values are set in unsigned types.

Change your code into:

```
var limit:uint = myVector.length-1;
for(var a:uint = limit; a > 0; a--)
{
    trace(a);
}
```

Comment: Makes sense that an iteration should happen when `a` is `0` but that it produces no output as the result is -1, which I suppose is where this whole issue arises from, but using `>` instead `>=` only outputs `2, 1` and ignores the element at index 0.

Answer (score 1):

In binary - first BIT of number is minus, that is in int values. In UINT value that is just a BIT of value.
One byte int looks like 1000 0000 == -127 and 0111 1111 = 127
One byte uint looks like 1000 0000 == 128 and 0111 1111 = 128

This is it.